# How can I save large plot in R in high resolution pdf

Tags: r, plot

When I run this command in R, I can generate the plot, but I need to plot it in such a way that I can see each and every element in this plot. This data has thousands of elements. So is there a way to save this plot in high resolution pdf, so I could zoom in and see every element in the plot without any obstruction?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1),font=2,font.lab=2,font.axis=2,mgp=c(3.1,1,0),mar=c(5,5,4,2)+0.1)

bp<-plot(as.numeric(vec[include,eig1]),as.numeric(vec[include,eig2]),pch=pch.array, cex=1.35,lwd=1.0,col = color.array[include], xlim=range.eig1,ylim=range.eig2,main="",xlab=eig1, ylab=eig2,cex.lab=2.0,cex.axis=2.0)
legend(range.eig1[1],range.eig2[2],classes,col=color.set,pch=pch.set,cex=0.85,bty="n",xjust=0.3)

text(as.numeric(vec[include,eig1]),as.numeric(vec[include,eig2]),labels=as.character(rownames(vec)[include]),col="Black", cex=0.34)
```

Comment: I believe that saving PNG format will give some of what you want right away.  Have you tried the default save options?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes it does save the plot, but it is very crowded and I want to save in very small fonts and possibly in high resolution pdf so I can zoom into  each of those points.

Comment: Maybe set the PDF page size to be very large?

Comment: Following up on comment by @Mars, `pdf(width = 32, height = 18 ,onefile = T)` followed by `your code` followed by `dev.off()` should do the trick. You can change the `width` and `height` arguments to make it as large as you need.